# Checking start up error messages in Emacs

Tags: emacs, startup

When I invoke Emacs, I see some error messages which are replaced by the main window (startup screen) pretty soon. How can I access these error messages?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error messages are stored in the `*Messages*` buffer.  There is a command to open it: `C-h e`. You can also just click on the echo area in the bottom of the window.

By default, the last 1000 lines of messages are saved.  You can change this by setting the variable `message-log-max`.